# mail send but its empty in php

Tags: php

i want to send mail and mail is going to send but problem is that mail is empty in mail box. What is the problem in my code?

```
$afile = $_FILES['myFile'];

//Getting info about above taken file
$fileatttype = $afile['type'];
$fileattname = $afile['name'];
$filesize=$afile['size'];
if($fileatttype=="application/octet-stream" or $fileatttype=="text/plain" or $fileatttype=="application/msword" or $fileatttype=="application/pdf") 
{
 $otherData="**********************Personal Details*********************\n

Position Applied For :$Position\n
First Name :$First\n
Last Name:$LastName\n
Date Of Birth :$DD-$MM-$yy\n
Correspondence Address :$Caddress1 $Caddress2 $Caddress2\n
Permanent Address :$Paddress1 $Paddress2 $Paddress2\n
Contact No(HOME):$Home\n
Mobile :$Mobile\n
E-Mail :$EMail\n
**********************Education*********************\n

Quallification :$Quallification\n
OtherCourse:$OtherCourse\n
**********************Previous Working Details*********************\n

Company Name-$WCompany1\n
Title-$WTitle1\n
CTC-$WCTC1\n
Reasons of Leaving-$WReason1\n
Company Name-$WCompany2\n
Title-$WTitle2\n
CTC-$WCTC2\n
Reasons of Leaving-$WReason2\n
Company Name-$WCompany3\n
Title-$WTitle3\n
CTC-$WCTC3\n
Reasons of Leaving-$WReason3\n
Company Name-$WCompany4\n
Title-$WTitle4\n
CTC-$WCTC4\n
Reasons of Leaving-$WReason4\n

Current CTC:$CCTC\n 
Expected CTC:$ECTC\n
Notice Period Required :$NoticePeriod\n
Total no of years experience :$TotalExperience Years\n
Current Location :$Clocation\n
Preferred Location:$Plocation\n
Resume:$Resume\n
**********************Family Details*********************\n
Father / Guardian Name :$Fname\n
Father / Spouse: Occupation:$Focc\n
Kids:$Kids\n
Age of Kids:$AOK\n
"; 
 $to="renu_activa@yahoo.co.in";
 $from=$_POST['First'];
 $subject=$Position;
 $headers = "From: $First";
 if($filesize>0)
    {
    $file = fopen($afile['tmp_name'],'rb');
    $data = fread($file,$afile['size']);
    fclose( $file );
    }
//Making a random number to use afterwards with help of current time
$semi_rand = md5( time() );

//Defining the type of email as Mime email
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x";

//Appending to headers, telling that its multipart message with text and attachment
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

//The text part of message in variable $otherData with other details
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" .
$otherData . "\n\n";
//Encoding all the data read from file to "base64" the standard for email attachments
$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));

//Appending the file data to the email including the file name etc
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type: {$fileatttype};\n" .
" name=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
" filename=\"{$fileattname}\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" .
$data . "\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}--\n";
$sentmail=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($sentmail)
{
header('location: career-with-us.php');
}
else
{
 echo "Mail Not Send Successfully....";
}
}
else
{
 echo "Wrong format: Please upload only PDF/DOC/DOCX/TXT file format...";
}
```

I am not getting why its empty neither textbox value nor file attachment is showing in mail. Its totally empty.

Answer (score 0):

You define a new variable for the body of the email.

```
$mess = 'Please check it';
$messa = '*****...
```

I'm assuming you meant

```
$mess = 'Please check it';
$mess .= '*****...
```